# Трудности с QR Сканером

Tags: c#, uwp

Необходимо сделать сканер QR кодов нашел библиотеку Zxing и примеры UWP к ней. Вроде бы все работает и считывает, но не показывает на экране, что видит камера(что достаточно неудобно) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть те, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, отпишитесь пожалуйста... Просто даже не знаю где рыскать, искать другие примеры или где то что то разрешить нужно или это просто не предусмотрено...

Вот на всякий случай код:

```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    UIElement customOverlayElement = null;
    MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Create a new instance of our scanner
        scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Dispatcher);
        scanner.Dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void buttonScanDefault_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Tell our scanner to use the default overlay
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
        //We can customize the top and bottom text of our default overlay
        scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode";
        scanner.BottomText = "Camera will automatically scan barcode\r\n\r\nPress the 'Back' button to Cancel";

        //Start scanning
        scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result != null)
                HandleScanResult(t.Result);
        });
    }


    async void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        string msg = "";

        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
            msg = "Found Barcode: " + result.Text;
        else
            msg = "Scanning Canceled!";

        await MessageBox(msg);

    }

    async Task MessageBox(string text)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {                
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(text);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, я нашел вполне нормальное решение для начинающего. http://www.soulier.ch/?p=2464

У меня оно работает на отлично + не так трудно разбираться в коде, как в официальных примерах ZXing. Единственным, хоть и незначительным, минусом этого примера я считаю это:

```
 while (true)
{
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imgProp, stream);

    stream.Seek(0);
    var wbm = new WriteableBitmap(600, 800);
    await wbm.SetSourceAsync(stream);

    var result = bcReader.Decode(wbm);

    if (result != null)
    {
        var msgbox = new MessageDialog(result.Text);
        await msgbox.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Т.е он фотографирует в непрерывном потоке, что занимает оперативную память. Если кто подскажет как это подправать, буду благодарен)